# Magento not working after migration server and change URL

Tags: php, magento

I have moved a magento site rackspace windows cloud server to another windows server that have plesk installed.

After migration I have changed my base URL from core_config_data to plesk site preview link and deleted all files from cache folder, Now when I am trying see my site using plesk site preview link firefox giving **The page isn't redirecting properly** error, on Chrome giving **This webpage has a redirect loop** error.

I have checked my plesk preview link with other files and see link is working fine but only magento not opening.

Any one know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewriting depends on your `.htaccess` file, so there are a couple of things to check:

web/seo/use_rewrites in core_config_data should be true.

when you created your tarball, did it include . files in the root directory especially .htaccess?

If you used tar -cvf archive.tar * then it may have missed them. (Nice "feature" of *nix).

Check that your httpd.conf has AllowOverride All, otherwise your local .htaccess will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you I am checking now

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed both of "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/secure/base_url"? if you changed only one - it can be not working.

Comment: Could you add a little explanation?

Comment: for example, if you changed only **"web/unsecure/base_url"** and you site is set to use **"web/secure/use_in_frontend"** to **"true"**, you may get the page, defined in **"web/secure/base_url"** and vice versa